# Why do torsion-free abelian groups admit linear orders?

Tags: group-theory, order-theory, abelian-groups

I have read a theorem that says that every torsion-free abelian group admits a linear order. The proof used tensor products and so was above my head. I tried to find another proof on the web and I found one which I also didn't understand, because it uses model theory of which I know nothing. It's [here](http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~rastr/Exercises/Marker/2/4.pdf). Wikipedia [gives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearly_ordered_group) a reference to a Levi paper which is supposed to prove this statement but I was unable to find it and can't know if it's my level mathematics.

My question is: is there a proof of this fact which can be understood by a student with group-theory knowledge just a bit above the first course?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you used to Zorn's lemma proofs? Because here is a quick one:

Let $A$ be a torsion-free abelian group. A sub-monoid of $A$ is a subset $P$ containing $0$ and closed under addition. We'll say that $P$ is *pointed* if it does not contain both $x$ and $-x$ for any nonzero $x \in A$. Clearly, the union of an ascending collection of pointed sub-monoids is itself a pointed sub-monoid. So, by Zorn's lemma, there is a maximal element pointed sub-monoid of $A$.

**Claim 1:** For any $x \in A$, and any positive integer $k$, if $kx \in P$ then $x \in P$.

**Proof:** Let $Q = \{ x  \in A : kx \in P\ \text{for some } k \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0} \}$. Note that $Q$ is a sub-monoid: It clearly contains $0$ and, if $k_1 x_1 \in P$ and $k_2 x_2 \in P$, then $k_1 k_2 (x_1+x_2) \in P$. We also claim that $Q$ is pointed: If there is $x \neq 0$ such that $k x \in P$ and $\ell(-x) \in P$ then $k \ell x \in P$ and $- k \ell x \in P$. Since $A$ is torsion-free, $k \ell x \neq 0$, contradicting that $P$ is pointed.

So $Q$ is a pointed monoid containing $P$ and, by the maximality of $P$, we have $Q=P$. In other words, if $kx \in P$ for $k>0$, then $x \in P$, as desired. $\square$

**Claim 2:** For any $x$ in $A$, either $x$ or $-x \in P$.

**Proof:** Suppose that $-x \not \in P$.

Let $P' = \{ y+nx : y \in P, n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \}$. Clearly $P'$ is a sub-monoid of $A$. We claim that $P'$ is pointed. If not, then we have $y_1 + n_1 x = - (y_2 + n_2 x)$ for some $y_1$, $y_2 \in A$ and some $n_1$, $n_2 \geq 0$ with $y_1+n_1 x \neq 0$.

So $y_1 + y_2 =- (n_1+n_2) x$. If $n_1=n_2=0$, then $y_1 = - y_2$ and, since $P$ is pointed, $y_1=y_2=0$. In this case, $y_1+n_1 x = 0$, while we assumed otherwise.

Alternatively, suppose that $n_1+n_2>0$. We know $y_1 +y_2 \in P$ and by claim 1, the identity $y_1 + y_2 =- (n_1+n_2) x$ then forces $-x \in P$, a contradiction.

So we now know that $P'$ is pointed. So $P'=P$ and $x \in P$, as desired. $\square$

With $P$ as above, define $y \leq z$ if $z-y \in P$. This is reflexive (as $0 \in P$) and transitive (as $P$ is closed under addition.) It is anti-symmetric (because $P$ is pointed) and a total order by the claim.

So we have equipped $A$ with a linear order. As $P$ is closed under addition, the order is compatible with the group structure, meaning that $w \leq x$ and $y \leq z$ means $w+y \leq x+z$.

Comment: Dear David: Wonderful! You wrote $P'=\{y+nx:y\in P,n\ge\mathbb Z_{\ge0}\}$. I think you intended to write either $P'=\{y+nx:y\in P,n\ge0\}$ or $P'=\{y+nx:y\in P,n\in\mathbb Z_{\ge0}\}$. I also think that you meant $y_1+y_2\in P$ instead of $y_1+y_2\in A$.

Comment: What is the third $\square$ related to? I can't see the meaning and relation of the paragraph beginning with "Now, $y_1+y_2\in P$.".

Comment: Dear @Damian: I guess the third $\square$ indicates the end of the proof of the statement contained in the question.

Comment: Dear @Pierre-Yves: I think you were rather right with your previous comment, ie. it is a remain of a previous version of the answer. The second $\square$ indicates the end of the proof of the claim 2, so the next paragraph has no meaning in this version of the answer. Let us wait for the David's explanation.

Comment: I understand perfectly now. Thanks again!

Comment: @DamianSobota The previous comment was mine. I deleted it because I thought David was the one with the last word here anyway, so my comment was unnecessary.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: one more thought came to my mind. It is worth to mention that the ordering induced by $P$ has this special property that given any $x,y,w,z\in A$ such that $x\le y,w\le z$ it is immediate that $x+w\le y+z$. If the ordering had no special property (this or other), than to be done we could just use the Zermelo's theorem about well-ordering which is equivalent to the Zorn's lemma.

And I have a question about references -- maybe you (or someone else) know a good book which introduces such theorems as above concerning groups?

Comment: Observation about compatibility with addition made explicit. I don't know any books on this sort of thing.

Comment: @DamianSobota I believe some books on group rings could have theorems on linearly ordered groups because when $G$ is linearly ordered, $RG$ has some nice properties. Passman's book might have something about it but I don't have it at hand.

Answer (score 4):

This proof won't be to everybody's taste, but let me offer it as an illustration of the power of ultraproducts and non-standard arguments.

First let's consider a finitary version of the question, and see if it's any easier: why do *finitely generated* torsion-free abelian groups admit linear orders? This is not hard to answer. Any such group is isomorphic to a direct product of infinite cyclic groups, and such a group admits a linear order, for example the [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Next, for an arbitrary torsion-free abelian group $G$ let its finitely generated subgroups $G_i$ be indexed by $I$. Take a non-principal [ultrafilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) $\mathcal{D}$ on $I$ that contains all subsets of $I$ of the form $E_x=\{i\in I:x\in G_i\}$ where $x$ ranges through $G$. (Since the sets $E_x$ have the [finite intersection property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property) it follows from Zorn's Lemma that such an ultrafilter exists.)

Now take the [ultraproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct) $\Pi_{i\in I}G_i/\mathcal{D}$ of its finitely generated subgroups $G_i$. One can now check that

(1) the map $g\mapsto(g_i)_{i\in I}/\mathcal{D}$, where $g_i=g$ if $g\in G_i$ and $g_i=1$ otherwise, is a well-defined injective group homomorphism. (The choice of $\mathcal{D}$ is crucial here.)

(2) The ultraproduct is linearly ordered. (The orders on the $G_i$ induce a linear order on $G$.)

(3) The linear order on the ultraproduct is compatible with the group operation.

The embedded image of $G$ therefore inherits a suitable linear order, so we are done.

One of the morals of this story is that one can often embed an object in an ultraproduct of its finitary subobjects (the details are typically similar to those above), and such an embedding often allows one to reduce the argument to the finitary case.

Comment: It seems like you're essentially re-doing the model-theoretic proof (or *a* model theoretic proof): if the OP doesn't understand model theory, I'm not sure ultraproducts are relevant to them

Comment: @Max Well, my proof doesn't presuppose any knowledge of model theory, even if it is model-theoretic in nature. I haven't given a full account of ultraproducts but have given links if the OP (or anyone else) wants to read further. I tried to follow the link in the question to the model theoretic proof to see if my proof might be of interest to the OP, but the link is broken. Six years have passed since the question was asked; perhaps her/his grasp of model theory has changed since. Finally I thought it was worth having an ultraproduct proof for anyone else who stumbles on this question.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use divisible groups to show the following statement (see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/425493/36434)):

> **Theorem:** Any torsion-free abelian group is embeddable into a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

Because any subgroup of a totally orderable group is itself totally orderable, it is sufficient to prove that a direct sum of totally orderable groups is itself totally orderable in order to conclude:

> **Property:** Let $(I, \leq)$ be a well-ordered set and $\{ (G_i, \leq_i) : i \in I \}$ be a collection of totally ordered groups. Then the lexicographic order with respect to $\leq_i$ totally orders $G= \bigoplus\limits_{i \in I } G_i$.

Comment: None escapes the Zorn' s lemma.

Answer (score 0):

The group $(\mathbb{Z}^n,+)$ (sum component-wise), is torsion free and is abelian, right? Also, $(\mathbb{Z}^n,\leq)$ (component-wise too) is a conditional complete lattice (but not a total order). What am I missunderstanding?

Comment: Can you write it as comment?