# How to construct a homomorphism from an abelian group to $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be an abelian group.

I don't know how to construct a nontrivial map from $A$ to the group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What abelian group $\,A\,$ ? If it isn't determined, why do you think there *must* be a non trivial map to $\,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z\,$ ?

Comment: See Weibel's book: An introduction to homological algebra, Chapter 2. He means we can find a nontrivial map!

Comment: maybe you can get help from T.S.Blyth's Module Theory book. see the chapter of Injective modules page 140.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a **divisible** module over the PID $\mathbb{Z}$, so it is **injective**.  (For definitions and proofs, see e.g. $\S$ 3.6 of [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf).)

Injectivity means: if $B$ is a submodule of $A$, then every homomorphism $f: B \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ extends to a homomorphism $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.  Since $A$ is nontrivial, it has a nontrivial cyclic subgroup $B$.  Defining a nontrivial homomorphism from a cyclic $\mathbb{Z}$-module to $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is easy: I leave it to you to find all such homomorphisms.

**Added**: I just checked Weibel's book.  The facts I mentioned in the first paragraph above are Corollary 2.3.2 on p. 39.  The OP's question is an exercise on p. 40.  So I have little doubt that this is the intended solution.

Comment: I think the problem can be reduced to the case of finitely generated abelian group, since $A$ is the direct limit of them. For this special case, it is easy.

Comment: @ksj03, you still have to show that you can extend from a subgroup to a larger subgroup (so as to be able to define a map on the direct limit), and it is in extending maps that the difficulty lies.

Comment: For a map from a finitely generated group to $G$, we need only to define on the basis. This definition is obvious compatiable with that on the larger f.g groups.

Comment: @ksj03: The compatibilities don't seem obvious at all.  You're saying to define the map separately on each finitely generated subgroup, but certainly most such families of maps will *not* be compatible.  Maybe this approach can be made to work, but at the very least you will need some structure theory of f.g. modules over PIDs to do so.  This might be worth another question.  By the way, is there something you find unsatisfactory about my answer and/or Mariano's?

Comment: Your injectivity argument is fine and Mariano's answer is Ok. But I don't want to use Baer's theorem. I just want to talk about it in the frame of abelian groups. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @kjso03: Baer proved Baer's Theorem for abelian groups.  Some years later its importance in the study of modules over a ring was observed.  If you have specific requirements on an answer, please put them in your question, along with motivation, if possible.  (E.g. *why* do you not want to use Baer's Theorem?)

Answer (score 2):

Let $G=\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$, and suppose $A\neq0$.

Consider the set $S$ of pairs $(B,\phi)$ with $B$ a non-zero subgroup of $A$ and $\phi:B\to G$ a non-zero homomorphism. The set $S$ is not empty: if $a\in A$ is any non-zero element, then the cyclic subgroup $(a)$ is non-zero and there is a map $\phi:(a)\to G$, as one easily sees.

There is a partial order on $S$, as follows: $(B_1,\phi_1)\preceq(B_2,\phi_2)$ iff $B_1\subseteq B_2$ and $\phi_2|_{B_1}=\phi_1$. One can easily check that the partially ordered ser $(S,\preceq)$ satisies the hypotheses of Zorn's lemma. There exists then a maximal element $(A_0,\phi_0)$.

Suppose $A_0\subsetneq A$, so that there is an element $x\in A\setminus A_0$.
There exists $n\in\mathbb N_0$ such that the subgroup $A_0\cap (x)$ of $(x)$ is generated by $nx$.

Let us suppose first that $n\neq0$, and set $y=\tfrac1n\phi_0(nx)\in G$. I claim that there is an homomorphism $\phi:A_0+(x)\mapsto G$ such that whenever $a\in A_0$ and $t\in\mathbb Z$ we have $\phi(a+tx)=\phi_0(a)+ty$. To check this,  we first need to show that this is well defined; do that and then check that we have an homomorphism.

Now $(A_0+(x),\phi)$ is an element of $S$ strictly larger than $(A_0,\phi_0)$! This is absurd, and therefore we must have $A=A_0$, so that $\phi_0$ is a homomorphism from $A$ to $G$.

we are left with the case in which $n=0$, which is easier. Try it :-)

Comment: It looks to me like you're proving the case of Baer's Criterion that is used in the proofs of the assertions in the first paragraph of my answer.  So it's a nice complement to mine.

Comment: Of course, Pete: that is what is to be proved. That's the actual meat of the thing!

Comment: Question about the first two paragraphs: If $a$ has order $n$, then I know that you can map $a$ to $1/n + \mathbb{Z}$. How to give a map when $a$ has infinite order?

Answer (score 0):

Any abelian group $A$ can be embedded into a divisible group $Q$ (see for example this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425431/embedding-torsion-free-abelian-groups-into-mathbb-qn/425493#425493)). Moreover, an abelian divisible group can be written as a direct sum of $\mathbb{Q}$ and [Prüfer groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group); so if $A$ is torsion-free (resp. a torsion group), we can suppose that $Q$ is also torsion-free (resp. a torsion group).

Let $A$ be a nontrivial abelian group and $T$ its torsion subgroup.

**Case 1:** Suppose $T=A$. Then $A \hookrightarrow \bigoplus\limits_{p \in K} \mathbb{Z}[p^{\infty}]$, and because $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z} \simeq \bigoplus\limits_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \mathbb{Z}[p^{\infty}]$, we deduce that $A \hookrightarrow \bigoplus\limits_{i \in I} \mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$. Now we can find a projection such that $A \to \mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ is nontrivial.

**Case 2:** Suppose $T \neq A$. Then $A/T$ is a nontrivial abelian torsion-free group, hence $A/T \hookrightarrow \bigoplus\limits_{i \in I} \mathbb{Q}$ and we can find a nontrivial projection $A/T \to \mathbb{Q}$. So $$A \twoheadrightarrow A/T \hookrightarrow \bigoplus\limits_{i \in I} \mathbb{Q} \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Q} \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$$

If the image of $A$ in $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ is trivial, its image in $\mathbb{Q}$ is included into $\mathbb{Z}$, so it is sufficient to compose by the automorphism $x \mapsto \frac{1}{2} x \in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Q})$ so that the given morphism can be supposed not trivial.

Comment: I like this answer. Thanks.