# An example of symmetric associative increasing function which cannot be represented as addition

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $X$ be some connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $f: X^2\to X$ have following properties:

1. $\forall x, y$: $f(x, y)=f(y,x)$ (Symmetry)
2. $\forall x, y, z$: $f(x, y)>f(x,z)\iff y>z$ (Strictly increasing on any argument)
3. $\forall x, y, z$: $f(x, f(y, z))=f(f(x, y), z)$ (Associativity)

We call $f$ addition-like, if there exists an injection $\phi:X\to\mathbb{R}$
such that $\forall x, y$: $\phi(f(x,y))=\phi(x)+\phi(y)$.

Can $f$ be not addition-like?

Some examples:

1. $f(x,y)=xy, x>0,y>0$, then $\phi(x)=\ln(x)$
2. $f(x,y)=xy+x+y, x>0,y>0$, then $\phi(x)=\ln(x+1)$

I do not know the answer to the question because I have trouble finding such $f$ at all except explitictly using addition/multiplication with some mapping, which obviously yields addition-like function by definition and multiplication being addition-like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f(x,y) = [x] + [y] + s(s^{-1}\{x\} + s^{-1}\{y\})$

Here $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$ and $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$ and $s$ is any order preserving bijection between $[0,\infty)$ and $[0,1)$ (e.g. the sigmoid function).

Then there’s no [edit: *order-preserving*] $\phi$ because there are infinitely many elements, namely any element of $[0,1)$, which *stay bounded under $f$*. By this I mean:

> Let $f^2(x) = f(x,x)$ and $f^n(x) = f(f^{n-1}(x), x)$. (For the case of addition this is just $n \cdot x$).
>
> Let's say an element $x$ *grows without bound positively (resp. negatively) under $f$* if for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $n$ such that $f^n(x) > t$ (resp. $f^n(x) < t$).
>
> Let's say an element $x$ *stays bounded under $f$* if it neither grows without bound positively nor negatively.

Then for the case of $\mathbb{R}$ with addition, only $0$ stays bounded under $+$, so there can be no order-preserving injection $\phi$ as above given that we have infinitely many elements which stay bounded under $f$.

Essentially this is using the additive structure of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ with the dictionary ordering as the order structure.

Added: If we don't require $\phi$ to be order-preserving, then additively $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \subset \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}$ as both are $\mathbb{Q}$ vector spaces of the same dimension, so there is a (necessarily non-order-preserving) $\phi$ for this example.

---

In general without the requirement that $\phi$ be order-preserving:

The commutative and associative properties of $f$ endow $X$ with the structure of a *commutative monoid* and the order property implies that it is *cancellative* and *torsion-free* (see [Affine monoid on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_monoid); not all of the properties on that page apply here as we are not in the finitely generated case).

Then the *group of differences* (see the article above again) of this monoid is a torsion-free commutative group in which it embeds. This then (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425431/embedding-torsion-free-abelian-groups-into-mathbb-qn)) embeds in a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space, which can be taken to be of cardinality at most $\mathbb{R}$, and thus embeds in $\mathbb{R}$ additively. The composition of these embeddings preserving the additive structure gives a map $\phi$ as in the question.

Comment: Interesting. Seems like it works if $\phi$ is presumed to be monotonous, but I am not sure that it cannot be some ugly function, which sends every $[n,n+1)$ into some everywhere dense subset.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Yes, if $\phi$ need not be order-preserving then there does exist such an "ugly function" in this case: see my added paragraph.

Comment: Tbh, I only thought about ugly map when read your proof, initially I considered nice maps (looking for non-addition-like functions in kinda topological sense, not that AC group mess). So despite the fact that I cannot fully verify the last part of the answer, since it's just too hard, I will accept it because your example with interval magic is exactly what I had in mind when posing the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko It’s an interesting problem how different properties of f affect the result. My example above is not continuous, and in fact is sort of an end run around what you maybe were trying to avoid with your requirement that X be connected. If we impose continuity, or maybe we need differentiability, I suspect we’d again find that $\phi$ can always be found. Possibly via some integration / diff eq solution. (We’d want something like the exponential map from Lie groups.)